# Cual es la principial diferencia entre IN,OUT e IN OUT en PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedure, plsql, toad

estoy trabajando en una base de datos **oracle** que maneja muchos procedimientos **PL/SQL** y **APEX**. No soy muy nato para la programación, pero estoy tratando de entender.

Fragmento de código

```
PROCEDURE create_request (out_OraErr out varchar2, out_request_no out 
                          number, out_request_id out varchar2)
```

Alguien me puede explicar ¿cómo funciona un procedimiento con parametros `OUT`? Ya lo leí en diferentes fuentes, pero prefiero que alguien me explique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tanto en los procedimientos almacenados como en las funciones, los parámetros pueden ser de entrada, salida o de entrada/salida:

**IN (entrada)**: Son los parámetros que recibe la función al ser ejecutada para ser insertados en la base de datos o determinar una lógica de negocio. Son siempre parámetros de *sólo lectura*:

```
PROCEDURE PR_TEST(pVariable IN VARCHAR2)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TABLE1(value1) VALUES (pVariable);

END PR_TEST;
```

**OUT (salida)**: Parámetros que normalmente se cargan dentro del procedimiento almacenado para luego devolver un valor. Es un parámetro de *sólo escritura* y no tendrá valor hasta que se le asigne uno dentro del procedimiento:

```
PROCEDURE PR_TEST(pVariable OUT VARCHAR2)
BEGIN

    SELECT VALUE INTO pVariable
    FROM TABLA1
    WHERE CONDICION = 1;

END PR_TEST;
```

**IN/OUT (Entrada/Salida)**: La combinación de los dos anteriores. Se recibe un valor para luego modificarlo (o no) y devolverlo. Es un parámetro de *lectura y escritura*:

```
PROCEDURE PR_TEST(pVariable IN OUT VARCHAR2)
BEGIN

    IF (pVariable = 'S') THEN
        pVariable := 'N';
    END IF;

END PR_TEST;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @zeross

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir parámetros de solo escritura o de solo lectura?

Comment: Un parámetro "solo lectura" solamente permite leer el contenido del parámetro, no permite modificarlo. "Solo escritura" son aquellos que se reciben sin valor y solamente se permite modificarlo para darle un valor de salida.

Answer (score 3):

Los procedimientos almacenados almacenan por ejemplo una sentencia SQL, que puede ser dinámica es decir trabajar por medio de valores que ingrese el usuario y con base en esos valores procesarlos y devolver un resultado:

**Caso `IN`**

Necesitamos un *SP* que haga un `SELECT` con base en el `id` que ingrese un usuario; entonces lo lograríamos de este modo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usuarios(IN idInt INT)
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =  idInt
END
```

**Caso `out`**

Nos ayuda a extraer de un *SP* el cálculo generado a través de una variable; de este modo:

```
CREATE PRODECURE total(OUT  total INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total
    FROM users
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PROCEDURE create_request (
  OUT OraErr, 
  OUT varchar2, 
  OUT request_no, 
  OUT number, 
  OUT request_id, 
  OUT varchar2
)
...
```

Los parámetros OUT son los de salida.  En el ejemplo, si llamás al procedimiento

```
SELECT create_request();
```

no necesitás parámetros de entrada IN, luego el procedimiento hace algo y devuelve: OraErr, varchar2, request_no, etc.

Aclaración: la sintaxis del ejemplo no es correcta.  Es sólo a fines ilustrativos para explicar los parámetros OUT.