# Stored Procedure de MySQL no retorna valores

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente **Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Ejemplo`@`%` PROCEDURE `Login`(NameUser VARCHAR(100), UserPassword VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
 SELECT id_SystemUsers FROM systemusers WHERE nameUser=NameUser AND userPassword=sha1(UserPassword) AND userStatus=1; 
END
```

Al momento de llamarlo

```
call Login("Ejemplo", "Ejemplo");
```

Me retorna los valores vacíos.

[image: Valores Vacíos Stored Procedure]

> **NOTA:** Probé el código sin parámetros y con ***valores preestablecidos*** y funciona correctamente

**Stored Procedure sin Parámetros y valores preestablecidos:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Ejemplo`@`%` PROCEDURE `Login`()
BEGIN
 SELECT id_SystemUsers FROM systemusers WHERE nameUser="Ejemplo" AND userPassword=sha1("Ejemplo") AND userStatus=1; 
END
```

Llamando al ***Stored Procedrue***

```
call Login();
```

Valores retornados

[image: Valores Reornados Stored Procedure sin Parámetros]

Lo que no entiendo es ¿Por qué uno si funciona y el otro no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa por la cual el procedimiento almacenado (stored procedure) no retorna valores (el comportamiento debería ser que retornara todos los valores) es porque el nombre de los parámetros coincide con el nombre de las columnas, por ejemplo, `NameUser` (parámetro), para MySQL, es igual a `nameUser` (columna).

Una opción para solucionar el problema es cambiar el nombre de los parámetros, por ejemplo a `_NameUser`.

Otra opción (menos recomendada) es mantener los nombres de los parámetros y de las columnas iguales pero cualficar las columnas, es decir, `systemusers.nameUser`.

Ver aquí todos los ejemplos [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97815faa919be61db5e4b547b7ef21a7).

Los parámetros en procedimientos almacenados (stored procedures) son considerados `IN` de manera predeterminada o *default* cuando no se indica explícitamente.

Documentación relacionada (disculpar, pero está en Inglés):

- [13.1.17 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)
- [24.8 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)
- [9.2.2 Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando a un procedimiento almacenado le pasas argumentos que después sustituyes por parámetros al momento de invocarlo le tienes que indicar si el valor es de ingreso, de salida o ambos.

Para este caso los 2 que indicas son valores que va a introducir el usuario por lo tanto son de ingreso que debes explícitamente marcar con la palabra reservada **`IN`**

Entonces debería alcanzar con indicar `IN` para ambos de este modo:

```
(IN NameUser VARCHAR(100), IN UserPassword VARCHAR(100))
```

El resto del cuerpo de tu *PA* del primer código que muestras debería quedar igual.

**Referencias**

- [Procedimientos almacenados en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: Excelente, en una oportunidad haré los cambios y probare el código, para aceptar la respuesta. Como pregunta extra me cuesta trabajo saber cuando es IN u OUT, agradecería una pequeña explicación en que casos usarlos.

Comment: @FernyCortez esa pregunta ya se realizó en la comunidad [justo aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280717/cual-es-la-principial-diferencia-entre-in-out-e-in-out-en-pl-sql) te invvito a leerla